# portfolio Jquery script crashing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, crash

I'm trying to create this portfolio page where there are 2 columns of images. On hover the image zooms and the next image is pushed away to reveal a caption.

I am new to javascript and I have it working but it is crashing my page after a few minutes of running. I'm sure this is not written in the best manner. anyone have feedback?

```
        function portImage() {

        $('.slide').mouseenter(
            function() {
                var imgResize = $(this).children('.slide-image').children('img');
                var current_h = $(this).children('.slide-image').children('img').height();
                var current_w = $(this).children('.slide-image').children('img').width();

                $(imgResize).addClass('active');
                $(imgResize).clone().insertAfter($(imgResize)).addClass('clone');
                $(this).find('.active').removeClass('active');
                $(this).find('.clone').filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
                    width: (current_w * 1.3),
                    height: (current_h * 1.3)
                }, {queue: false, duration: 300});
        }).mouseleave(
            function() {
                var imgResize = $(this).children('.slide-image').children('img');
                var current_h = $(this).children('.slide-image').children('img').height();
                var current_w = $(this).children('.slide-image').children('img').width();

                $(this).find('.clone').filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
                    width: (current_w + 'px'),
                    height: (current_h + 'px')
                }, {queue: false, duration: 300});
        });


    };


        function leftSlide() {
    $('.slide.left').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).next('.slide.right').animate({
                right: "-25%"
            }, 500);
            $(this).children('.slide-caption').animate({
                right: "-50%"
            }, 500);

        },
        function(){
            $(this).next('.slide.right').animate({
                right: "0"
            }, 500);
            $(this).children('.slide-caption').animate({
                right: "0"
            }, 500);
        });
};

function rightSlide() {
    $('.slide.right').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).prev('.slide.left').animate({
                left: "-25%"
            }, 500);
            $(this).children('.slide-caption').animate({
                left: "-50%"
            }, 500);

        },
        function(){
            $(this).prev('.slide.left').animate({
                left: "0"
            }, 500);
            $(this).children('.slide-caption').animate({
                left: "0"
            }, 500);
        });
};

portImage();
rightSlide();
leftSlide();
```

I have it set up on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cuestadesign/jej9xrfq/

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of your `.clone()` function in the `mouseenter` event handler of the `portImage()` function.

You are setting `var imgResize` to all the children `img`es of `$(this).children('.slide-image')`.  The first time around this only grabs the one image.  However, you then clone that image and add it as a sibling to that image.  The next time around, your function will assign both images to `var imgResize` and clone them both/animate them both, etc...

This results in exponential growth of images being cloned and animated, resulting in a page crash after only a few iterations.

The solution?  As far as I can tell, just removing the clone after it's been animated up and back down solves everything:

```
$(this).remove();
```

That would go in a callback function of the `.animate()` function in the `mouseleave` event handler of your `portImage()` function, like so:

```
$(this).find('.clone').filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
        width: (current_w + 'px'),
        height: (current_h + 'px')
    }, {queue: false, duration: 300, complete: function() {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

You may also want to change assignment of `imgResize` to not include items with a class of `.clone`:

```
var imgResize = $(this).children('.slide-image').children('img:not(.clone)');
```

[**JSFiddle Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/jej9xrfq/1/)